# Flash Videos go fullscreen once (firefox), then after minimising it and trying to go fullscreen again it freezes (Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome Desktop)

Tags: gnome, firefox, flash, fullscreen

I just made a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was working fine, the problem is though that after I switched to Gnome Desktop, I couldn't switch to fullscreen mode on flash videos once I already did that (Flash would freeze, but the audio would be playing fine). I am using Firefox, and I already tried updating to the newest version of flash.

I am aware that this question was already asked once [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456265/ubuntu-14-04-videos-refusing-to-go-fullscreen-and-freeze-on-firefox), but I figured since this didnt get answered I would ask again.

Thanks.